# How do I destroy a child object if I set the relation to nil and save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :image, optional: true, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

I tried to set the relation to nil and save, and expected the record in the database to be deleted, but it was not. How can I ensure the child object is deleted to avoid orphans?

```
irb(main):005:0> u.image
=> #<Image id: 27, file_file_name: "anita-roddick.png", file_content_type: "image/png", file_file_size: 119348, file_updated_at: "2017-10-12 02:08:01", created_at: "2017-06-12 22:11:57", updated_at: "2017-10-12 02:08:02">
irb(main):006:0> u.image = nil
irb(main):007:0> u.save
=> true
irb(main):008:0> u.image
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> i=Image.find 27
=> #<Image id: 27, file_file_name: "anita-roddick.png", file_content_type: "image/png", file_file_size: 119348, file_updated_at: "2017-10-12 02:08:01", created_at: "2017-06-12 22:11:57", updated_at: "2017-10-12 02:08:02">
```

§ 4.1.2.4 says the only options are `:destroy` and `:delete`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: By setting `u.image` to `nil` you're essentially setting the `image_id` attribute of the `user` instance to a `nil` which removes the association (the id) with the image but does not destroy the image instance itself.

Comment: Does `image` has a dependency destroy on its users?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Image class has no relations defined. 3 different classes have images as children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First
>
> The `dependent: :destroy` will only delete/destroy the dependency when
>   the parent record is destroy. you should use this to get rid of orphan
>   records.

This is how I would do something like this.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :image, optional: true, dependent: :destroy
  before_save :check_images, :only => [:update]
  ...
  private
  def check_images
    if image_id.nil? && image_id_changed? 
      Image.find(image_id_was).destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this can help you and put you in the right tack

Comment: Ahh with a callback. Thanks. I edited to only destroy when it changes from not-nil to nil. I don't think `#find(nil)` would work if `image_id` was first set.